# Redirect after registration laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im using the standard laravel registration and login pages. Im trying to figure out how to add a redirect after user registration. Under my AuthController i have found that i can do the following:

```
protected $redirectPath = '/interest';
```

However this redirects my users here when they log in too. I just want to have this after the user registers an account. How can I do this?

Comment: How are you handling registration/authentication? This redirect should happen after a user has successfully submitted the registration form and if the account creation was deemed successful.

Comment: Have you tried just using a normal ol' redirect in the method? `return redirect('/interest');`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using either **AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers** trait or both **AuthenticatesUsers** and **RegistersUsers** trait. That's one of situations when you'll get such behaviour.

The reason why user gets redirected to **/interest** is because both authentication and registration process use the same **redirectPath()** method to determine URL where user should be redirected and that uses the **$redirectPath** property of your controller.

One option could be to overwrite **redirectPath()** method and return different paths depending whether user is authenticated (after login) or not (after registration). Unfortunately **it won't work** with those traits, as Laravel's registration process authenticates automatically newly registered users.

Easiest **solution** to this problem would be to split registration and authentication into 2 separate controllers. Each of them would have their own **$redirectPath** property.

Answer (score 0):

The AuthController is making use of the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers trait, and because it is a trait you can override the methods so you can place the postRegister in your AuthController and redirect where you need to, something like this.

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect()->route('name_of_the_route');
}
```

This will auth your new users and the redirect them to the route you specify, and only affect the registration and not the authentication, if you do not want to auth the new users you could change the `Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));` line for this `$this->create($request->all());`